# Inject service depending on configuration in Java EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi, java-ee-7

My application currently uses a class into which two services get injected with the `@Inject` annotation.

```
@Stateless
public class MyClass {

  @Inject
  private SomeService someService;

  @Inject
  private OtherService otherService;
}
```

Both services are pretty similar and both extend an abstract `Service` class.

Here's what I'm trying to do...

My basic idea is that the `MyClass` class would look something like this:

```
@Stateless
public class MyClass {

  @Inject
  private Service service;
}
```

Depending on a configuration the application decides to either inject `SomeService` or `OtherService`

**Example:**

```
if (config.getValue().equals("some_service")) {
  return new SomeService();
} else if (config.getValue().equals("other_service")) {
  return new OtherService();
}
```

Does Jave EE provide a solution for this?

Comment: Did you try  putting your 'if-then-else-if-then' code in a `@Producer` annotated method? Should just work...

Answer (score 2):

To make this work, you'll need to ensure that whatever "makes" `SomeService` eliminates `Service` from the list of types it can make, and whatever "makes" `OtherService` eliminates `Service` from the list of types *it* can make.

For example, if `SomeService` is a simple managed bean, you'll need to add the `@Typed(SomeService.class)` annotation to it:

```
@Typed(SomeService.class)
public class SomeService extends Service {

}
```

If, on the other hand, `SomeService` is produced by a producer method you'll have to do the same thing analogously:

```
@Produces
@ApplicationScoped
@Typed(SomeService.class)
private SomeService makeSomeService() {
  return fabricateSomeService();
}
```

The `@Typed` annotation restricts the set of types to whatever is given, not what is inferred.

If you do this on both "concrete" services, then your `getService()` producer method as written in your answer above should work.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the `@Typed` annotation. I new there was something more to it!

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by: "Depending on a configuration..." When do you decide what to use? At compiletime or runtime?

There are severaly ways to get this done:

**1. @Alternative and beans.xml**

Annotate SomeService and OtherService with @Alternative and activate one of them again in beans.xml with

```
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">

    <alternatives>
        <class>SomeService</class>
    </alternatives>

</beans>
```

**2. With qualifier and Producer:**

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER})
public @interface First {}
```

And annotate both Beans with:

```
@First
@Stateless
public SomeService{ ...  }
```

Now you can have a Producer-Class that looks like follows:

```
@Dependent
public class ServiceProducer {

  @Inject
  @First
  private Service someService;

  @Inject
  @Second
  private Service otherService;

  @Produces
  @Default
  public Service getService() {
    switch (someCondition) {
        case SOME:
            return someService;
        case OTHER:
            return otherService;
        default:
            return null;
    }
  }   
}
```

And finally inject the Service where you want to use it:

```
@Inject
Service service;
```

**3. Without Producer but with Qualifier-Annotations**

You need to Annotate SomeService and OtherService to get this to work.

```
@Inject
Instance<Service> services;

public void someBussinessMethod(){
    Annotation qualifier = someCondition ? new AnnotationLiteral<First>() {} : new AnnotationLiteral<Second>() {};
    Service s = services.select(qualifier).get();
}
```

**4. Without Qualifier**

This ist in my eyes the ugliest and slowest solution but you can iterrate over the Injectend services and decide by the Class if you want to use it.

```
@Inject
Instance<Service> services;


public void doSomething() {

    Class clazz = someCondition ? SomeService.class : OtherService.class;

    Service first = services.stream().filter(s -> s.getClass() == clazz).findFirst().get();


}
```

A detailed explenation can be found here:
https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/learn/userguide/CDI-user-guide.html#injection

Answer (score 0):

With respect to the comment by @kukeltje I used the `@Produces` annotation like this:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyProducer {

  @Inject
  private SomeService someService;

  @Inject
  private OtherService otherService;

  @Produces
  @ApplicationScoped
  public Service getService() {
    switch (someCondition) {
        case SOME:
            return someService;
        case OTHER:
            return otherService;
        default:
            return null;
    }
  }   
}
```

**Usage:**

```
@Stateless
public class MyClass {

  @Inject
  private Service service;
}
```

Comment: Can you please also add the piece of code where you inject the `@Produces  Service`? I would expect Injecting the Services and then producing one of them to generate an error about ambiguity since `SomeService` and `OtherService` both implement `Service` and `@Produces Service` is the third. So I'd expect a clash (but I'm no expert)

Comment: I added the code how I use this injection. So far I'm not running into any problems.

Comment: ok, you are injecting in an EJB, maybe that explains why there is no 'ambiguity' error